# I made a CLI calculator and I am wondering, how can I have the program accept numbers indefinetly until the user inputs a stop command?

Tags: java, double, command-line-interface, java.util.scanner, calculator

You probably understand that I am a beginner, and I know that we aren't really liked by the community.
I made a multi purpose calculator a while back and now I want to expand it. In this question I will be focusing only on one class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

    public static void calcMenu(Scanner input){
        Scanner oper = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input the First number:");
        double anum = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Please input on of the following operations:");
        System.out.println("+");
        System.out.println("-");
        System.out.println("*");
        System.out.println("/");
        String equ = oper.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please input the Second number:");
        double bnum = input.nextDouble();

        switch (equ){
        case "+":
            System.out.println(anum + bnum);
            break;

        case "-":
            System.out.println(anum - bnum);
            break;

        case "*":
            System.out.println(anum * bnum);
            break;

        case "/":
            System.out.println(anum / bnum);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

In this Java class, the program can solve equations only with two numbers. I would like to make it like in a standard calculator, where you can input the numbers as much as you want. I would like to do it until the user types something like "done"  and the application will return to the main menu.
This is probably a very nooby question but please help. And if you want to see the whole application: here's the [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0h0HYD9sk5hR2lnamJVN1ZQc3c?usp=sharing)

Comment: the code for that will be completely different. You want user to add expression at once or asking questions like enter next operator then enter next number and so on

Comment: @HarishBarma But how can I have the user add the expression at once?

Comment: It is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you out! :)

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {

private static double answer;
private static boolean done = false;
private static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       try {
           new Calculator().calcExpression();
       } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
           System.out.println("An error occurred. ");
       }
   }

   private void calcExpression() throws InputMismatchException {

       System.out.println("Enter Your Expression Here:");

       System.out.print("Num: ");
       double firstNum = in.nextDouble();
       in.nextLine();

       while (!done) {

           System.out.print("Operator: ");
           String operand = in.nextLine();

           if (operand.equals("=")) {
               break;
           }

           System.out.print("Num: ");
           double secondNum = in.nextDouble();
           in.nextLine();

           calculate(firstNum, operand, secondNum);
           firstNum = answer;
       }

       System.out.printf("Answer is %.2f", answer);
   }

   private void calculate(double num1, String equ, double num2) {

       switch (equ)

       {
           case "/":
               answer = (num1 / num2);
               break;

           case "*":
               answer = (num1 * num2);
               break;

           case "+":
               answer = (num1 + num2);
               break;

           case "-":
               answer = (num1 - num2);
               break;

           case "=":
               done = true;
               break;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I still have not learned how to use the "try" loop, so I did not use it. Also, I am still having trouble with "private" classes and variables, so I made them public.

Comment: Your welcome. _More about Exception handling_ - [Here](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/try-catch-in-java/)

And You should always make instance variables **private**